# How to Save state of user Login using air?

Tags: jquery, sqlite, air, session-state

i am building application using air, jquery, and sqllite as database local.
Now, i build module for login that reads from database. But, i am confuse how to save state of user login to the application. For example if we use PHP, we can save state of user in Session or Cookie. How about air?.. How can i do for saving the state of user? Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

By using EncriptedLocalStore, we can save an variable in our localdisk.. so it will be preserve before removed variable.